# Java code written in MPL, says it's wrong?

Tags: java

I need to write down some code, but MPL says it's wrong? Could't figure out what was wrong?

Write the definition of a class  Counter containing:

- An instance variable named  counter of type  int .
- An instance variable named  limit of type  int .
- A static  int variable named  nCounters which is initialized to  0 .
- A constructor taking two  int parameters that assigns the first one to  counter and the second one to  limit . It also adds one to the static variable  nCounters .
- A method named  increment . It does not take parameters or return a value; if the instance variable  counter is less than  limit ,  increment just adds one to the instance variable  counter .
- A method named  decrement that also doesn't take parameters or return a value; if  counter is greater than zero, it just subtracts one from the  counter .
- A method named  getValue that returns the value of the instance variable  counter .
- A static method named  getNCounters that returns the value of the static variable  nCounters .

My code I wrote:

```
public class Counter {

    private int counter;
    private int limit;
    private static int nCounters = 0;

    public Counter(int counter, int limit) {
        nCounters++;

    }

    public void increment() {
        if (counter < limit) {
            counter++;
        }
    }

    public void decrement() {
        if (counter > 0) {
            counter--;
        }
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return counter;
    }

    public static int getNCounters(){
        return nCounters;
    }
}
```

MPL says:

> Remarks:
>            ⇒     Your constructor does not initialize counter properly
>            ⇒     Your code had an error during execution
>
> Problems Detected:
>            ⇒     value of counter is incorrect

Comment: Surely at least the first "remark" from MPL is quite clear? (And it should have said the same thing for `limit`.)

Comment: And the rest follows from there methinks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

explanation has been given by @T.J. Crowder

and he meant this:
modify your constructor like this:

```
public Counter(int counter, int limit) {
  this.counter = counter;
  this.limit = limit;  
  nCounters++;

}
```

in your code your constructor wasn't initializing those instance variables

Comment: Thank you. Yes maybe, but giving 50% of the answer and thinking that a newbie in Java like me will understand it doesn't help me. Thanks for the example

Comment: @F4LLCON: the bulk of effort in answering this question correctly went to TJ Crowder, and his answer should have been accepted.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Before the 'bulk' of information was written, Bingo answered my question. After Bingo, TJ Crowder edited his answer and explained the rest.

Answer (score 4):

Surely at least the first "remark" from MPL is quite clear? (And it should have said the same thing for `limit`.) It's saying that your constructor never initializes `counter`. And indeed, it doesn't. Your constructor is:

```
public Counter(int counter, int limit) {
    nCounters++;

}
```

Within that, you want to set your instance variables `this.counter` and `this.limit` to something (probably you want to set them to the values of the arguments that have the same names).

---

Re your comment:

> If I knew what you where talking about, I could figure it out myself. Maybe some more explanation about the this.counter part?

If you don't understand the above (and we were all newbies once!!), I'd recommend stepping back and working through a good, basic Java book and/or tutorial.

A "constructor" is a function that is called automatically as part of creating an instance of a class (an object). (An "instance" is one specific in-memory object.) So for example, when you do

```
Counter c = new Counter(1, 10);
```

...you're calling the constructor of the `Counter` class to create an *instance* of that class. The constructor in Java is defined much like a method is defined, but with no return value, so what I've quoted above is your constructor for the `Counter` class.

An "instance field" (or "instance data member") is effectively a variable that relates to a specific. You have two of them in your class: `counter` and `limit`, which you've declared like so:

```
private int counter;
private int limit;
```

You also have a class (or "static") field called `nCounters`:

```
private static int nCounters = 0;
```

The "arguments" to your constructor are the things you put in the parentheses in the constructor definition, so your `counter` and `limit`. Even though they have the same names (in your example) as your instance fields, they are not related to them in any way. You could have called them `c` and `l` if you liked.

What MPL is telling you is that you haven't set an initial value for ("initialized") `counter` in your constructor. It should tell you the same thing about `limit`. They'll have Java's default initial value for `int` fields, which is `0`. But since you're accepting arguments into your constructor, you probably want to use those. For example:

```
public Counter(int counter, int limit) {
    this.counter = counter;
    this.limit = limit;
    nCounters++;
}
```

I've had to write `this.counter =` rather than just `counter =` because the argument has the same name as the instance field. If it didn't, `this.` would be optional. (I'm not a fan of leaving it off, but a lot of people are.)

Comment: If I knew what you where talking about, I could figure it out myself. Maybe some more explanation about the this.counter part?

Comment: @F4LLCON: With respect (really!), if you don't understand what I'm saying above, I would recommend going through some basic Java books and tutorials. I've added some detail.

Comment: Thank your for the detailed explanation. Yes of course, I really need to learn the basics and remember them better.

Comment: @F4LLCON: You're welcome! As I said, we're all newbies at everything once. :-)